# How do I centre align two BTN button within a jumbotron in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS and trying to build something which resembles a homepage.

Please see attached screenshot.

How can I centre align these two buttons BTN within a jumbotron in my HTML project.

[image]

> My HTML

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Bespoke Recruitment Solutions</h1>
        <p class="lead">We are an indapendant recruitment company specialising in providing bespoke HR services.<br> We take the time to understand our clients vision, goals and culture allowing us to engage with the right talent to fill the vacany.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Submit Your CV</a><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Fill A Vacancy</a></p>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add class `text-center` to `<p>` where your buttons are.

**HTML**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Bespoke Recruitment Solutions</h1>
        <p class="lead">We are an indapendant recruitment company specialising in providing bespoke HR services.<br> We take the time to understand our clients vision, goals and culture allowing us to engage with the right talent to fill the vacany.</p>
        <p class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Submit Your CV</a><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Fill A Vacancy</a></p>
      </div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/126/)**

Comment: LOL we made the same answer!

Comment: what a blessing this site is. Thank you very much

Comment: Before I up vote and for my own knowledge, may I ask. what does the p class lead do?

Comment: The <p> element represents a paragraph. The class `text-center` in bootstrap is the same as `text-align:center` rule,  so,  .text-center{ text-align: center;}

Answer (score 1):

As you are using boostrap, add the 'text-center' class to your `<p>`

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Bespoke Recruitment Solutions</h1>
        <p class="lead">We are an indapendant recruitment company specialising in providing bespoke HR services.<br> We take the time to understand our clients vision, goals and culture allowing us to engage with the right talent to fill the vacany.</p>
        <p class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Submit Your CV</a><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Fill A Vacancy</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

simply `text-align: center` is the solution.

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/aLnrqv9b/1/)

**CSS:**

```
.center{
  text-align: center;
}
```

**Updated HTML:**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Bespoke Recruitment Solutions</h1>
        <p class="lead">We are an indapendant recruitment company specialising in providing bespoke HR services.<br> We take the time to understand our clients vision, goals and culture allowing us to engage with the right talent to fill the vacany.</p>
        <p class="center"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Submit Your CV</a><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Fill A Vacancy</a></p>
      </div>
```

As jumborton is a bootstrap then you can use just a class name `text-center` to the `paragraph p` of button.

Here is the example-

```
<p class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Submit Your CV</a><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Fill A Vacancy</a></p>
```

Comment: Is there any one else who downvote to my answer? Is there anything wrong with this answer? who did this downvote?